# How to build dynamic SQL query in DBIx::Class view

Tags: sql, perl, postgresql, dbix-class

I have a complex SQL statement that I'd like to use in DBIx.
So instead of building it the ususal, 'abstract' way, I figured I'd use a View (DBIx::Class::ResultSource::View) for this particular case instead.

Here is my query from the original DBI code:

```
    SELECT a."key", CASE WHEN $language = ''
            THEN a."default" ELSE $language END AS lan
FROM foo.regionlang as a
INNER JOIN foo."displayPageKeys"  as b ON a."key" = b."key"
WHERE a.regions LIKE '%,$region,%'
    AND b."displayPage" = ?
UNION
SELECT a."key", CASE WHEN $language = ''
            THEN a."default" ELSE $language END AS lan
FROM foo.regionlang as a
INNER JOIN foo."displayPageKeys"  as b ON a."key" = b."key"
WHERE regions like '%,0,%'
    AND b."displayPage" = ?
```

So in my view it looks like this:

```
__PACKAGE__->result_source_instance->is_virtual(1);

__PACKAGE__->result_source_instance->view_definition(q[
SELECT a."key", CASE WHEN ? = ''
            THEN a."default" ELSE ? END AS lan
FROM foo.regionlang as a
INNER JOIN foo."displayPageKeys"  as b ON a."key" = b."key"
WHERE a.regions LIKE '%,$region,%'
    AND b."displayPage" = ?
UNION
SELECT a."key", CASE WHEN ? = ''
            THEN a."default" ELSE ? END AS lan
FROM foo.regionlang as a
INNER JOIN foo."displayPageKeys"  as b ON a."key" = b."key"
WHERE regions like '%,0,%'
    AND b."displayPage" = ?
]);
```

I tried replacing *$language* by using the *bind* call, which I use to replace any values in my query:

```
    my @transl_hashrefs = $self->{schema}->resultset('View::Translation')
        ->search(
            {},
            {
                result_class => 'DBIx::Class::ResultClass::HashRefInflator',
                bind => [
                            $langmap,
                            $langmap,
                            $display_page,
                            $langmap,
                            $langmap,
                            $display_page,
                        ],
            } )
        ->all;
```

I should mention that said query is being called on Postgres, so the working SQL should look something like this:

```
    SELECT a."key", CASE WHEN "lang1" = ''
            THEN a."default" ELSE "lang1" END AS lan
FROM foo.regionlang as a
INNER JOIN foo."displayPageKeys"  as b ON a."key" = b."key"
WHERE a.regions LIKE '%,$region,%'
    AND b."displayPage" = 'home'
UNION
SELECT a."key", CASE WHEN "lang1" = ''
            THEN a."default" ELSE "lang1" END AS lan
FROM foo.regionlang as a
INNER JOIN foo."displayPageKeys"  as b ON a."key" = b."key"
WHERE regions like '%,0,%'
    AND b."displayPage" = 'home'
```

The issue is that I have to get the value of *$language ("lang1")* somehow in double quotes ("") in the SQL. This doesn't work using the *bind* way, which is designed for values, not fields I guess.

One can also pass vars using bind and access them like $1, $2, etc in the View. But even like that I cannot put the value inside double quotes.

Sorry for the most likely, very confusing question. I tried to make it as clear as possible.

Any help is much appreciated!

cheers

Comment: I'm wondering if all you need is to replace `q[` with `qq[` (qq allows for variable interpolation) and then replace the `?` with `$language`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I forgot to mention: I tried qq already. It seems that DBIx doesn't understand the placeholders if using qq: Statement has no placeholders to bind at /usr/local/share/perl5/DBIx/Class/Storage/DBI.pm line 1889. at /usr/local/share/perl5/DBIx/Class/Schema.pm line 1077

Comment: The abbreviation dir DBIx::Class is DBIC not DBIx which is a whole namespace.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem where plain views didn't help (mostly because if you join the view to other tables, add other criteria and limit the rows received, the binds can get mixed up with the params.

The solution I ended up going with was considerably more complex than your needs, but at the root of it is a recent module that Ovid wrote called DBIx::Class::Report.  It may not be on CPAN yet, but it is on github, and he outlines it here: http://blogs.perl.org/users/ovid/2015/03/dbixclassreport---generate-ad-hoc-dbic-classes-from-sql.html

With this, you can dynamically create the view with arbitrary SQL, so the identifier that doesn't work well in a bind can be interpolated, and the rest of the criteria can be bound normally for security/performance.

Comment: This a really great idea, thanks a lot! I was looking for something like this for quite a while now, so I'm gonna try if it works for me.